# Wordpress Gutenberg block rendering invalid HTML on save.js component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have a problem when creating a custom Gutenberg block in a Wordpress project. I'm using the [@wordpress/create-block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/create-block) library for this.

The issue I'm having is when trying to edit the block once it has been saved. I'm creating a block to add a simple quote and author with the **RichText** component. This is the **edit** function in my *edit.js* file

```
export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps()
    const { quote, author } = attributes

    const onChangeQuote = newQuote => setAttributes({ quote: newQuote})

    const onChangeAuthor = newAuthor => setAttributes({ author: newAuthor})

    return (
        <div { ...blockProps }>
            <RichText
                tagName="div"
                onChange={ onChangeQuote }
                value={quote}
                placeholder={__( 'Add Quote' )}
                className="quote"
            />

            <RichText
                tagName="div"
                onChange={ onChangeAuthor }
                value={author}
                placeholder={__( 'Add Author' )}
                className="author"
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

It's just a function to save a Quote and an Author.

This is my **save** function in my *save.js* file

```
export default function save({ attributes }) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save()
    const { quote, author } = attributes

    return (
        <div { ...blockProps }>
            <div className="quote">{ quote }</div>
            <div className="author">{ author }</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And this is how the block is being saved in my database

```
<!-- wp:pull-quote-test/pull-quote-test --><div class="wp-block-pull-quote-test-pull-quote-test"><div class="quote">Test</div><div class="author">author</div><div class="test">Test</div></div><!-- /wp:pull-quote-test/pull-quote-test -->
```

So everything thus far is working correctly, the issue is when trying to edit the post again, if I reload the page then I get this error message

[image: error message]

Somehow, the save function is returning a different HTML from the one saved in the database. This is the return object

[image: output object]

You can see that the variables are concatenated, so WordPress is saying the block has invalid information.

To add more information, this is the block.js attributes I've added for the component

```
"attributes": {
    "quote": {
        "type": "string",
        "source": "text",
        "selector": "div"
    },
    "author": {
        "type": "string",
        "source": "text",
        "selector": "div"
    }
}
```

If anyone has any idea of what may be causing this issue and how to solve it I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem is that your attribute selectors are ambiguous.
Try being more specific

```
"attributes": {
    "quote": {
        "type": "string",
        "source": "text",
        "selector": ".quote"
    },
    "author": {
        "type": "string",
        "source": "text",
        "selector": ".author"
    }
}
```